# Migrating to `prop-types` causes warning on context usage

Tags: reactjs

After upgrading to react `15.6.0` (or `15.5.x` for that matter) and replacing usage of `React.PropTypes` with `prop-types` package I'm getting an error when using my library (`inversify-react`):

```
Warning: Failed context type: Calling PropTypes validators directly is not supported by 
the `prop-types` package. Use PropTypes.checkPropTypes() to call them.
```

It seems that the error is caused by `context` usage, however libraries like `react-router` which also use `context` don't seem to have this problem. Did anyone encounter similar issue? Any hints how to avoid the warning?

Library source code: https://github.com/kukkimonsuta/inversify-react
Sample source code: https://github.com/kukkimonsuta/inversify-react-sample
Live sample: https://inversify-react-sample.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Are you using any other library?

Comment: `react`, `react-dom`, `inversify` are the other dependencies. I'm sure `inversify-react` is causing this.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am trying to use context without having to import use `prop-types`, because I am using flow.

Comment: I did not. Let me know if you make any progress on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the warning was mistake on my part where I accidentally bundled `prop-types` into the library instead of only using it as dependency.